# According to Tendai, is karma an illusion and all there is

Tags: truth, tendai

I think the conventional, mundane, truth in Tendai is the claim that karma is an illusion, for a number of reasons, such as the identity of the perfect mundane truth with the Madhyamaka ultimate truth. Zhiyi  -- importantly -- quotes Nagarjuna's Middle Treatise:

> All things that arise through causes and conditions, I explain as
> emptiness, Again, this is a conventional designation. Again, this is
> the meaning of the Middle Way.

---

I believe that in Tendai the conventional truth is just a different means of asserting the ultimate truth, that each of the three truths are both one truth, and different

> although three [phrases], they are one [in meaning]; although one,
> this is three; [they are] not mutually exclusive.

means of verbally falsifying reality

> The three types are all empty because they are beyond verbalization
> and conceptualization. The three types are all conventional because
> they merely exist as [provisional] verbal [con- structs]. The three
> types are all the Middle, because they are identical to the true
> aspects [of reality]

---

So I wondered if the Buddhist law of cause and effect all there is to Buddhism -- and Buddhahood and reality -- according to Tendai, yet also an illusion.

> Things are neither merely nominal, nor merely real

Ziporyn, 2012, 60

Inescapable, but unreal.

Comment: any feedback on the downvote? it's not a tricky inference

Comment: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear"? Why are you asking? Why do you think Tendai's "middle way claim" is about karma? Maybe add some quote of what you're asking about? Or don't bother -- I think I've understood now what your "inference" was but it isn't especially obvious at first reading.

Comment: i've already said haven't i? cos the equate causation with the ultimate truth @ChrisW

Comment: I read [this](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1568/42437) recently -- usually I might upvote a question (from a new user) just for being on-topic -- but I thought, "maybe we could start to ask that more experienced users could ask questions *well*".

Comment: right so i need references? @ChrisW ? i guess i'm too lazy, sorry

Comment: Something like references might make the question more interesting and/or easier to answer.

Comment: ok i'll get back to it later, cheers @ChrisW

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Is the title right too, a good summary of the question? If I tried to summarise the text I might try, "*Does Tendai's Middle Way merely assert causation, without assuming its reality or non-reality?*". Is that the same as the current title, which asks about "karma" and whether that "is" and "all there is"? And (apart from the title) do you want to mention why you're asking the question, or do you reckon that's obvious or unimportant?

Comment: it's unimportant. cheers @ChrisW i'll add another edit

Comment: i appreciate the help with the question. an answer may have made it more readable @ChrisW

Comment: i'll get back to this